# delete selected row from gridview and and update databse in vb.net windows form

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, window

I have a Delete button and i am trying to delete selected rows from gridview and database by clicking on that button. but having following code i am getting error like Argument out of range and convert to int.

```
 Private Sub dltButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dltButton.Click
        'Dim StudentId As String
        'StudentId =
        'con.Open()
        'cmd.CommandText = "delete from KaiyumVbStudent where StudentID = '"&StudentId&"'"
        'cmd.Connection = con
        Dim i As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index
        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0))
        con = New SqlConnection(constring)
        con.Open()
        Me.StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index)
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Delete from KaiyumVbStudent where StudentID = '@StudentID'", con)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Call databind()

Private Sub databind()
        con = New SqlConnection(constring)
        con.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("Select *from KaiyumVbStudent", con)
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        dt = New DataTable()
        dt.Load(dr)
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First put our code in try catch statement and check student Id datatype
Your are missing one statement 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", StudentID);
I hope you it is work..